# How to apply arel table on a list of objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have an array of objects contacts which has fields like first name, last name, middle name.

I am looking to use AREL function "match" to iterate through the contacts array and compare the fields with a search string.

How do I do it?

I have a contact Class with a method search.
Search:

```
 def search(query)
    q = “%#{query}%”
    c = Contact.arel_table
    contacts = Contact.where(c[:last_name].matches(q).
                   or (c[:middle_name].matches(q)))
  end
```

Now, I am looking to apply this method to an array of contact objects.

Comment: Can you please post some code to look at?

Comment: Please update this information in your question itself.

Comment: Do you really mean an array, or do you actually need to apply that to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is a collection as well and is returned by most AR methods, such as associations or conditions?

Comment: Yes, It's an ActiveRecord::Relation and not really an array.